# Is there a default method to count the identical elements in a jList?

Tags: java, model, double, element, jlist

I'm working on a Java project. 
I have a jList containing strings.

Explanation:

Example jList: "test", "test2"

If i add a string "test" to that jList, is it possible to just put '2' in front of test? My goal is to not have doubles in the jList.

Comment: You need to be more specific on what you want. This means providing sample input and output scenarios and the like.

Comment: Your question is very simple, yet it seems you didn't put any effort into solving it by yourself. Please provide an attempt to solve this, so we can point the right direction forward

Answer (score 0):

`list.getComponentCount()` gives you the components added to that list **including** the list itself.